# saving images from webcam stream directly to web server with java

Tags: java

Is it possible to save images directly from the webcam of my system to a web server in Java? Maybe it can directly passed to an URL address and can be `GET` at the server or anything else.

Comment: Do you want to save images (as you're saying in the body of your question) or audio file (as you're mentioning in the subject)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Java Media Framework (JMF)](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/index.jsp) to capture images from a webcam using Java. The JMF enables you to capture the current shot into an [`java.awt.Image`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/) object (part of the Java SE's built-in Java 2D API). Finally you can use the [Java 2D API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) to write the captured shot in under each the JPEG format to an `OutputStream`. This can be the [`URLConnection#getOutputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream%28%29) of the [`URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) of the web server.

You really shouldn't use `GET` for this. This way you're forced to send the image data encoded as a query string, which in turn has limitations in length. You don't want to be dependent on that. Better use `POST` instead. You need to do `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true)` to trigger `POST`. Alternatively you can use the [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) for to send it as a multipart/form-data request according the standards.

Assuming that you're using a `Servlet` on the server side, you just need to implement `doPost()` method accordingly to extract the image from the [`HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream%28%29). Alternatively, if you're using the HttpClient to send a multipart/form-data request, you can use the [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) for this.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

depends on your webcam /Webcam software . Lots of webcams come with software which stores the images in a directory. Configure the software and your web server in such a way that the images or streams are accessible from your webserver. That's all.

This way you can easily check on your web page for new webcam images and display them.

If your webserver is remote, do the same trick by installing a small server or java tool which checks for new images in the configured directory. If it finds some, write some code which posts those images as upload to your remote web server.

Hope that helps.